# Replace or Update a Table Row - based on the presence of a matching row item

Tags: update, insert, replace

Unfortunately I know next to nothing about php coding that contains some sql code. The examples I have seen online do not seem to match the same syntax that I inherited with this code, which is making this task confusing for me.

I have a database table called "effort" that contains two columns:

```
Column 1 = ad

Column 2 = theEffort
```

This line of code below works, and it will populate the table with the proper values for both the "ad" and "theEffort"

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO effort SET ad='$ad', theEffort='$theEffort'";
```

But I do not want the table to grow over time and contain redundant rows pertaining to the same ad. Each "ad" in this table should be unique. But each "ad" could have 5 different effort values, e.g., "theEffort" can be "easy", "medium", "difficult", "impossible".

The "ad" is 13 digit number, i.e. SFAD_000001234

Does anybody know how to modify my code above using similar syntax so that it would first check to see if the "ad" exists in the database table called "effort". And if so, instead of entering a new row it would update "theEffort" to the new value. And if the "ad" did not exist in any table row within the "effort" database then it would execute the INSERT INTO function, i.e., insert both the "ad" and "theEffort" as a new table row.

Thank you in advance,
-Jeff

Comment: first of all which rdms are you using, second your code is **vulnerable** to **sql inejction** so use **prepared statements with paramters**

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! What is your database server? I'm guessing MySQL (normally is with PHP...) but it might be something else - also, with any question, please include the version of your db server (and any other s/ware relevant to the question). Also, please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE effort\G`.

Comment: "13 digit number, i.e. SFAD_000001234" ?

Comment: I am using mysql on a Dreamhost labeled as phpMyAdmin version 4.8.5 - probably not specifics you are asking for?
I have included what I was searching for, which would get a matching row based on a matching item and either update or insert a new row.
I apologize for having such limited knowledge. 

$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE adads set theEffort='$theEffort' WHERE ad='$ad'";
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO adads SET ad='$ad', theEffort='$theEffort'";

 
$result = $db->query($sqlGet);

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    $db->query($sqlUpdate);
} else {
    $db->query($sqlInsert);
}

Comment: You might want to have a look a the concept of [**UPSERT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) (MySQL Dev).